# async/await - dispatching redux actions: dispatching an action causes my app to freeze

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux, expo

I am creating an app using Expo SDK 26 - I am working on a piece where I need to upload a photo into firebase database. For android and ios - Expo provides Image Picker to allow native access to gallery/capturing an image.

When I receive an image - I am trying to capture the image uri, fetch the image and upload it to firebase storage with a reference to the images firebase storage url saved in my firebase database.

When I select the image from a device, my action creator is triggered, but when I dispatch an action - the app stops at the dispatch. Am I missing something obvious, or is the pattern not correct?

If so - what would be a good approach to this.

Select Image From Device Code:

```
async _pickImage(){
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 3],
  });

  if (!result.cancelled) {
    this.props.uploadPhoto(result.uri)
  }
};
```

Upload Image Code:

```
export const uploadPhoto = (uri) => {
return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.UPLOAD_PROFILE_IMAGE_REQUEST
    })
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
    const userId = currentUser.uid;
    const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(userId);
    const databaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child("/users/" + userId + "/user-details")

    await ref.put(blob)
        .then((snapshot) => {
            databaseRef.update({
                "photoURL": snapshot.downloadURL
            }).then(() => {
                console.log(snapshot.downloadURL)
                dispatch({
                    type: ActionTypes.UPLOAD_PROFILE_IMAGE_SUCCESS,
                    payload: snapshot.downloadURL
                })
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({
                type: ActionTypes.UPLOAD_PROFILE_IMAGE_FAILURE,
                error: error
            })
        })
}
}
```

Reducer: UPLOAD_PROFILE_IMAGE_REQUEST

```
    import * as ActionTypes from '../ActionTypes'

    const INITIAL_STATE = {
      userInfo: {},
      error: "",
      isLoading: false,
      image: undefined
    };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE , action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

      case ActionTypes.GET_USER_DETAILS_REQUEST:
        return {...state, isLoading: true }

      case ActionTypes.GET_USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
        return {...state, isLoading: false, userInfo: action.payload}

      case ActionTypes.GET_USER_DETAILS_FAILURE:
        return {...state, isLoading: false, error: action.payload }

      case ActionTypes.UPLOAD_PROFILE_IMAGE_REQUEST:
        return {...state, isLoading: true}

      case ActionTypes.UPLOAD_PROFILE_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
        return {...state, image: action.payload, isLoading: false}

      case ActionTypes.UPLOAD_PROFILE_IMAGE_FAILURE:
        return {...state, error: action.payload, isLoading: false}

      case ActionTypes.CLEAR_USER_DETAILS:
        return {INITIAL_STATE, isLoading: false}

      default:
        return state
    }
}
```

I have tried console.log directly after the first dispatch but nothing prints in the log after the UPLOAD_PROFILE_IMAGE_REQUEST action dispatch.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you add a console.log before dispatching, does it appear? Also, you are dispatching an action of type ```ActionTypes.UPLOAD_PROFILE_IMAGE_REQUEST```, where do you handle it? Can you post this code?

Comment: @soutot this is really odd - after extensive testing yesterday trying to make this function work - it kept freezing when dispatching an action  - I tried to restart the simulator/tried on multiple different simulator devices. This morning after restarting my computer everything seems to be working as expected. I have updated the code in my post to show the Reducer function - but would you have any suggestions on this intermittent behaviour?

Comment: Hi all - I have been able to explain this intermittent behaviour - I am not sure if it is an issue on the redux-logger, redux or the react-redux npm libraries - but when I am debugging my application with redux-loggers in my middleware with the diff attribute set to true - it causes the app to freeze on any dispatched actions causing a change to state. This has occurred now (after further testing) in many areas of the app. A simple fix was to switch diff to false, a more complicated question - how/who do we mention this potential bug to?

Comment: if your tests conclusion is it's a bug, I think you can address it in the official repo in github: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux

Comment: @soutot thank you for the information I will try raise awareness of this on github.